# Get int value from database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

How i can get int value from database?
Table has 4 columns
Id, Author, Like, Dislike.

I want to get Dislike amount and add 1.
i try

```cs
var db = new memyContext();
var amountLike = db.Memy.Where(s => s.IdMema == id).select(like);
memy.like=amountLike+1;
```

I know that this is bad way. 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is here, but there's a few things that might help.

First, if you're retrieving via something that reasonably only has one match, or in a scenario where you want just one thing, then you should be use `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`, respectively - not `Where`. `Where` is reserved for scenarios where you expect multiple things to match, i.e. the result will be a *list* of objects, not an object. Since you're querying by an id, then it's fairly obvious that you expect just one match. Therefore:

```
var memy = db.Memy.SingleOrDefault(s => s.IdMema == id);
```

Second, if you just need to *read* the value of `Like`, then you can use `Select`, but here there's two problems with that. First, `Select` can only be used on enumerables, as already discussed here, you need a single object, not a list of objects. In truth, you can sidestep this in a somewhat convoluted way:

```
var amountLike = db.Memy.Select(x => x.Like).SingleOrDefault(x => x.IdMema == id);
```

However, this is still flawed, because you not only need to read this value, but also write back to it, which then needs the context of the object it belongs to. As such, your code should actually look like:

```
var memy = db.Memy.SingleOrDefault(s => s.IdMema == id);
memy.Like++;
```

In other words, you pull out the instance you want to modify, and then modify the value in place on that instance. I also took the liberty of using the increment operator here, since it makes far more sense that way.

That then only solves part of your problem, as you need to persist this value back to the database as well, of course. That also brings up the side issue of how you're getting your context. Since this is an EF context, it implements `IDisposable` and should therefore be disposed when you're done with it. That can be achieved simply by calling `db.Dispose()`, but it's far better to use `using` instead:

```
using (var db = new memyContext())
{
    // do stuff with db
}
```

And while we're here, based on the tags of your question, you're using ASP.NET Core, which means that even this is sub-optimal. ASP.NET Core uses DI (dependency injection) heavily, and encourages you to do likewise. An EF context is generally registered as a scoped service, and should therefore be *injected* where it's needed. I don't have the context of where this code exists, but for illustration purposes, we'll assume it's in a controller:

```
public class MemyController : Controller
{
    private readonly memyContext _db;

    public MemyController(memyContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    ...
}
```

With that, ASP.NET Core will automatically pass in an instance of your context to the constructor, and you do not need to worry about creating the context or disposing of it. It's all handled for you.

Finally, you need to do the actual persistence, but that's where things start to get trickier, as you now most likely need to deal with the concept of concurrency. This code could be being run simultaneously on multiple different threads, each one querying the database at its current state, incrementing this value, and then attempting to save it back. If you do nothing, one thread will inevitably overwrite the changes of the other. For example, let's say we receive three simultaneous "likes" on this object. They all query the object from the database, and let's say that the current like count is 0. They then each increment that value, making it 1, and then they each save the result back to the database. The end result is the value will be 1, but that's not correct: there were three likes just added.

As such, you'll need to implement a semaphore to essentially gate this logic, allowing only one like operation through at a time for this particular object. That's a bit beyond the scope here, but there's plenty of stuff online about how to achieve that.